# My computer is hacked, All files were renamed as YYZA file extension, how to rename or remove YYZA Extension?

Tags: virus, malware-removal, ransomware

My Laptop got attacked by a virus and nearly every file including Photos, Videos and Documents extension were changed to YYZA , meaning .jpg was changed to .YYZA, How to recover or remove that extension. kindly help?

Comment: Is your laptop running Windows?  Unless you have a backup or are using volume shadow copy you may be out of luck.

Comment: YYZA is Ransomware - your files are encrypted with a key known only to the hackers. Recovery chances are very slim. Hopefully you have an uninfected backup. Here's a very long writeup of what you can do to satisfy yourself that the files are in fact gone. https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-yyza-ransomware-virus/

Comment: @squillman, Volume Shadow Copy is a mere snapshot. And MS Backup, to a live drive, is *also* likely encrypted by the malware. A true *drive image*, on *separate media*, i.e., not connected at the time of the disaster, is the only sure means of recovery.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [STOP / DJVU](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/671473/stop-ransomware-stop-djvu-puma-promo-support-topic/) variant.

Some variations can be decrypted using the [Emsisoft decryptor](https://www.emsisoft.com/en/ransomware-decryption/stop-djvu/)

If your variant isn't supported yet, all you can do is wait and try every now and then if an updated version can. The tool is silently updated (updates aren't announced).

I happen to have made a simple free tool to repair certain file types but I no longer support or actively maintain it. Biggest flaws are, limited file size support and only atom order ftyp-mdat-moov is supported for QuickTime container based videos. Some commercial tools can now do the same, WonderShare Video Repair for example.

[image]

See https://youtu.be/3AKJ27sZ9_E. Download URL is in video description.

Since STOP / DJVU encrypts only first 153605 bytes of a file, there are more file types that are potentially repairable, for example: https://youtu.be/ouSTB6Rg10g.

Answer (score 0):

The damage you outline is quite serious. Ransomware.

The only thing you can do now is a fresh reinstall of Windows.

Then recover documents from your previous backup.

If no backup, you have just learned the importance of having backups

Answer (score 0):

Do not pay the ransom !

First step is to remove the YYZA virus. Try to scan using your anti-virus,
but if it fails you could try
[Gridinsoft Anti-Malware](https://howtofix.guide/download/)
that is said to detect well this virus.

For decrypting the files, you could use the
[Emsisoft Decryptor](https://www.emsisoft.com/ransomware-decryption-tools/download/stop-djvu).

Lastly, I hope you have good backups, as the last resort is
to format the disk and reinstall Windows from scratch.

The above advice is based on the article
[YYZA Virus (.YYZA File) Decrypt & Removal Guide](https://howtofix.guide/yyza-virus-file/#How_To_Decrypt_yyza_Files).
I suggest reading this article carefully (although it's rather long).

Comment: BTW, some who *do* pay the ransom find they cannot recover the files, anyway. Restore from your last disk image.

Comment: I agree, I have indeed seen several times people actually having paid without receiving a working decryptor.